# Apache Ignite Topology Snapshot refreshed .Net

Tags: ignite

I start the Apache Ingnite node, a server node, and another client node.

My scenario is: Close the client node, and how to update the service node Topology Snapshot at the same time.

Now, the Topology Snapshot is refreshed only when the NodeFailed event is received by the server after 20 seconds.

**What method or configuration on the server side can receive the NodeFailed event immediately or refresh the Topology Snapshot?**

**This is server log:**

```
[09:08:50,522][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#45%ignite-instance-f69c161b-9f38-4576-b52b-ef3077ba3156%][GridDiscoveryManager] Node FAILED: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=5f346db2-50fd-4d83-b518-a09690569274, consistentId=5f346db2-50fd-4d83-b518-a09690569274, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.40.1, 192.168.50.135, 192.168.65.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [DESKTOP-1BLUS7R/192.168.40.1:0, /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.65.1:0, /192.168.50.135:0], discPort=0, order=3, intOrder=3, lastExchangeTime=1602810475243, loc=false, ver=2.8.1#20200521-sha1:86422096, isClient=true]
[09:08:50,525][INFO][disco-event-worker-#45%ignite-instance-f69c161b-9f38-4576-b52b-ef3077ba3156%][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=5, locNode=f6d3f760, servers=1, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=6, offheap=1.5GB, heap=2.0GB]
[09:08:50,525][INFO][disco-event-worker-#45%ignite-instance-f69c161b-9f38-4576-b52b-ef3077ba3156%][GridDiscoveryManager]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=1, online=1, offline=0]
```

[

Comment: This problem has been solved by modifying the configuration on the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can reduce the service node attribute `ClientFailureDetectionTimeout`, increase the server check the frequency of client nodes.`The default is 30 seconds`.

```
//
// 摘要:
//Gets or sets the failure detection timeout used by Apache.Ignite.Core.Discovery.Tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi
//and Apache.Ignite.Core.Communication.Tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi for client nodes.
[DefaultValue(typeof(TimeSpan), "00:00:30")]
public TimeSpan ClientFailureDetectionTimeout { get; set; }
```